# Querying Orderreference number in order object

Tags: standard-objects

Hello group,
                    There is a field called order reference number in order object.But For what purpose this field is used and i am  not able to query this field in sales force Dev console.Any insight on this field?

Comment: Could you query OrderReferenceNumber field on Order object ?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used the object yet, but I would assume that the Order Reference field is just that, i.e. a user defined Reference number for the Order.

It is possible to query this field like this:

```
Select OrderReferenceNumber from order
```

Comment: This query throws an error. Not sure why SOQL does not allow querying a standard field of type TEXT(80)